# Unable to connect server via putty and winscp

Tags: linux, shell, lamp

By mistake i ran the command **shutdown -r now** which causes connection error when i am connecting server via putty and winSCP.

How can i connect to the server?

shutdown -r now command reboot the system but i dont think so it get restart.
It might be shut down so couldn't able to connect.

Putty Fatal Error : Connection Time Out

Comment: Turn the server back on.

Comment: @Mathew : Yes that only i need to know that how can i turn on server again?

Comment: Well if it's a remote server you have to call someone I guess.

Comment: But in my experience, if a Linux server doesn't reboot properly on it's own, someone of the admins might want to look at that. Because something is definitely not configured correctly on that server.

Comment: @Mathew: Ok..i think this would be the better instead of doing anything myself :) thanks for your help!!

Comment: Yes actually i have logged in as a root user in linux box..and i ran the above command...after that i couldn't able to connect the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not do it your self if you rent a server from datacenter . You need to call network support guyz to turn on the system. Thats the only way..